# Selenium script is not consistent

Tags: python, selenium, wait

I have other examples, but for this specific example what the code does is locate a series of elements that each link to a specific page. Then I click on a specific link. Sometimes this code works, but sometimes it does not work and the page just stays the same without clicking on the link.

I have used a variety of methods like sleep, wait and ActionChains in an attempt to make things more consistent, but it still messes up really frequently.

```
print(f"No.{i} Opportunity found {optitle_list[i]}")
#click on tender
time.sleep(10)
opentender_button =WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//img[@src = 'esources/theme/images/view.png']")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(opentender_button[int((j-3)/10)]).double_click().perform()
```

Here is another example. In this code the keys 'health' are not always sent, resulting in the wrong search options being reviewed by my script.

```
#Enter into Search box ‘health' and hit "Enter" key
time.sleep(20)
search_box = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label//input[@type='text']")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(search_box).double_click(search_box).send_keys('health').perform()
print("Search box filled")
```

Comment: Maybe the XPath changes, this can happen sometimes, have you tried to find the element by other unique identifiers like id/class/tag ?

Comment: I have tried stuff like that. But if the XPATH changes wouldn't there be some kind of exception like a NoSuchElement? 

For my code, most frequently what happens is that there is no exception and the code thinks it is running smoothly when in fact it has not clicked the button to the link

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should've thrown an exception. Initially I used to try other identifiers and when that fails, I tried to find the `href` and then use `driver.get()` to reach the page for scrapping. If this also doesn't satisfy then I suggest you to execute JS code using Selenium. `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath('the xpath'))`. I am not sure why this is happening too, but I have been lucky enough to get the results when I  change to any one of these ways.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but could you explain finding href and using driver.get()? I do not understand thank you

Comment: Find the tag which has the destination url and get the `href` attribute. I used this in one website `driver.get(driver.find_element_by_id('id or any other identifier that has the destination url').get_attribute('href'))`. This opens the destination url without a click. The problem is that it was more time and energy consuming when done in a `loop`. Alternative : If the url is not hidden under a script use `BeautifulSoup` to extract the destination link, which is smother than `Selenium` but won't work with JS effectively, and then use `driver.get()`.